# Insert few characters before character in a string variable (javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have this following javascript variable.

```
var data = "ashley, andy, juana"
```

i Want the above data to look like this.

```
var data = "Sports_ashley, Sports_andy, Sports_juana"
```

It should be dynamic in nature. any number of commas can be present in this variable.

Can someone let me an easy way to achieve this please.

Comment: This isn't a site to have people do your homework for you. If you have made an attempt then show the code, otherwise ask a more specific question than "Can someone do this for me?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `.replace` should work to add sports before each comma. Below I have included an example.

```
var data = data.replace(/,/g , ", Sports_");
```

In that example using RegExp with g flag will replace all commas with `Sports,` instead of just the first occurrence.

Then at the end you should just be able to append `Sports` to the end like so.

```
data = "Sports_" + data;
```

Comment: Please do not use W3Schools as a credible reference.

Comment: @4castle Any reason why?

Comment: Yes, also `.replace` only replaces the _first_ instance - won't work for everything: `data.replace(",", "Sports,"); //"ashleySports, andy, juana"`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: @CharlieFish- i updated my qustion. there is a slight difference in question. can you please have a look

Comment: @CharlieFish- do we have to do anything different for the last. juana part. since now Sports_ is to be added in front of juana

Comment: @brso05 Tell that to 4castle then :P

Comment: @CharlieFish don't worry about that lol everyone has their own opinion...but it is exactly that an opinion.

Comment: @brso05 Thanks haha

Comment: @4castle anyone can create a website and put whatever they want. That **doesn't** make it a fact. Why don't u find an actual example of something wrong on W3Schools then come back and post it.

Comment: @brso05 Please see this [meta discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280478/5743988). If you disagree, make your case there.

Comment: @4castle again all **opinions** come back with factual evidence please. Find me something on W3Schools that is blatantly wrong.

Comment: @4castle Each situation is unique. I still haven't heard a reason from you why [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) was bad.

Comment: Also you might want to read both links you posted...and read them in full.

Comment: @brso05 I'm not saying it's bad. I'm saying that if you use official links such as to W3C or some other commonly used source in the community, you will be teaching others to dig deeper.

Comment: @brso05 An example of a page that causes many people grief is the page for [`z-index`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) in CSS. It completely skips over the nuances of what a stacking context is or why a higher `z-index` often times won't actually work. It's like this in many of the docs. They don't dive deep enough to show what bugs could happen later.

Comment: @brso05 [The page for `replace`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) totally skips over describing special characters in the replacement string or how to use capture groups effectively. My answer would need those details explained.

Comment: @4castle i didn't say W3Schools is the only place to go or even the best. But if his answer was supported or enhanced by a W3Schools page there is nothing wrong with using it.

Comment: @brso05 I never said you thought that, or that there was anything *wrong* with using the link. My only statement was that *there are better sources*.

Comment: @4castle **"Please do not use W3Schools as a credible reference"**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120458/discussion-between-4castle-and-brso05).

Answer (score 2):

Probably an overkill, but here is a generic solution

```js
function sportify(data) {
  return data
    .split(/\s*,\s*/g) //splits the string on any coma and also takes out the surrounding spaces
    .map(function(name) { return "Sports_" + name } ) //each name chunk gets "Sport_" prepended to the end
    .join(", "); //combine them back together
  }

console.log(sportify("ashley, andy, juana"));
console.log(sportify("ashley   , andy,     juana"));
```

- [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)
- [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [`Array.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Answer (score 2):

Use a regex to replace all occurrences of a `,` or the beginning of the string using [`String#replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```js
var input = "ashley, andy, juana"
var output = input.replace(/^|,\s*/g, "$&Sports_");
console.log(output);
```

Comment: @4castle- thanks for this. i updated my question slightly. can you pelase have a look and let me know how to get that

Comment: @4castle- i am getting Sports_ashley,andy,juana as output with your code.

Comment: Ahh, that's because your input didn't have spaces. I updated to make the spaces optional.